# Executing 'bash -c' in 'docker exec' command

Tags: bash, docker, docker-exec

*Context:* I'm trying to write a shortcut for my daily use of the `docker exec` command. For some reasons, I'm experimenting the problem that my output is sometimes broken when I'm using a bash console inside a container  (history messed up, lines overwrite each other as I'm writing, ...)

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49281526/5018771) that you could overcome this problem by adding some command before starting the bash console.

---

Here is a relevant excerpt of what my script does

```
#!/bin/bash
containerHash=$1
commandToRun='bash -c "stty cols $COLUMNS rows $LINES && bash -l"'

finalCommand="winpty docker exec -it $containerHash $commandToRun"
echo $finalCommand
$finalCommand
```

Here is the output I get:

```
winpty docker exec -it 0b63a bash -c "stty cols $COLUMNS rows $LINES && bash -l"
cols: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
cols: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47289872/5018771) that this had to do with parsing and expansion. However, I can't use a function or an `eval` command (or at least I didn't succeed in making it work).

If I execute the first output line directly in my terminal, it works without trouble.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Some tips might be found at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: @EricRenouf Thanks! I already stumbled upon this in my research but could not seem to find a paragraph that does apply to my case... Do you see one that fits? (3rd section maybe but I don't quite understand it)

Comment: Have you considered the initial part of just storing the arguments in an array instead of a string?  Also, is it possible  either `COLUMNS` or `LINES` contains an unexpected newline or something like that?  perhaps those should be quoted as well?

Comment: I've tried replacing `COLUMNS` and `LINES` with hardcoded values but it did not help. Which part would you write as an array? If I take the command and execute it directly in the terminal, it works, that's what I don't get

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not Docker related, but Bash (*In other words, the docker's part of the command works well, it's just bash grumbling on the container like it would grumble on your host*):

#### Minimal reproducible error

```
cmd='bash -c "echo hello"'
$cmd

hello": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
hello": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

#### Fix

```
cmd='bash -c "echo hello"'
eval $cmd

hello
```

---

#### Answer

```
foo='docker exec -it XXX bash -c "echo hello"'
eval $foo
```

This will let you execute your command `echo hello` on your container, now if you want to add dynamic variables to this command (like `echo $string`) you just have to get rid of single quotes for double ones, to make this works you will have to escape inner double quotes:

```
foo="docker exec -it $container bash -c \"echo $variable\""
```

---

#### A complete example

```
FOO="Hello"
container=$1
bar=$2

cmd="bash -c \"echo $FOO, $bar\""
final_cmd="docker exec -it $container $cmd"

echo "running command: \"$final_cmd\""
eval $final_cmd
```

Let's take time to dig in,

- `$FOO` is a static variable, in our case it works exactly like a regular variable, just to show you.
- `$bar` is a dynamic variable which takes second command line argument as value
- Because `$cmd` and `$final_cmd` uses only double quotes, variables are interpreted
- Because we use `eval $final_cmd` command is well interpreted, bash is happy.

Finally, a usage example:

```
bash /tmp/dockerize.sh 5b02ab015730 world
```

Gives

```
running command: "docker exec -it 5b02ab015730 bash -c "echo Hello, world""
Hello, world
```

Comment: I think I understand. But there is still something bothering me: with this solution, I have to hard-code the variables: `foo='winpty docker exec -it 0b63a bash -c "stty cols 255 rows 59 && bash -l"'` in my case. Do you know a pretty way to use the variables inside the command? I could eval them after one another then glue the whole thing but it doesn't feel right

Comment: Yes, let me fix my answer