# How to delete a GitLab personal access token in docker using bash?

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab

### Context

After having been able to add a GitLab personal access token using bash with:

```
add_gitlab_personal_access_token(){
  local gitlab_username="$1"
  local token_name="$2"
  local personal_access_token="$3"
  local docker_container_id="$4"
  
  output="$(sudo docker exec -i "$docker_container_id" bash -c "gitlab-rails runner \"token = User.find_by_username('$gitlab_username').personal_access_tokens.create(scopes: [:api], name: '$token_name'); token.set_token('$personal_access_token'); token.save! \"")"
}
```

### Attempts I

Using the `docker exec` and `bash -c` command as used in setting the token allows one to revoke the token:

```
revoke_token(){

    local docker_container_id="$1"
    local token="sometokenpersonalgitlabtoken"
    output="$(sudo docker exec -i "$docker_container_id" bash -c "gitlab-rails runner \"PersonalAccessToken.find_by_token('$token').revoke! \"")"
    echo "output=$output"
}
```

### Issue

However, after trying to add the token again, it is still in GitLab, and GitLab returns:

```
DETAIL:  Key (token_digest)=(somelongkeysasdfasdfasdfkeyending=) already exists.
```

so the revoke method does not actually delete the token, it merely revokes it.

### Question

I was wondering how: *How can one delete the GitLab personal token in the docker container using bash (based on the `$token_name`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing 'bash -c' in 'docker exec' command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214436/executing-bash-c-in-docker-exec-command)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it did not resolve the issue. Primarily I am experiencing some difficulties with the command that is used by `gitlab-rails` to revoke the token. Additionally, I expect that once it has been revoked, it has not yet been deleted. In essence, when I try to create a new token with the same name(which has been revoked) expect GitLab to throw an error saying; that token has already been used.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the revoke command completes successfully, as far as gitlab-rails is concerned? Can you get into an interactive bash shell in the container and see those commands working for the sake of diagnosis, if you construct them manually?

Comment: @JeffBowman no. However, I did verify the revoke method works by seeing the token get removed inside the GitLab server through the browser. I think so, however, the answer of the question I think can be considered that one should not want to delete a GitLab token, merely revoke it. I was unaware of that at the time of writing my question. Hence I see more value in other actions. Thanks for suggesting a different verification strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question I think is: *It's a feature, not a bug.* I assume it is bad security practice to re-use a token, so instead of trying to delete an old token, I wrote a method that automatically generates random tokens.

The revoke method in the question works. It has been manually verified by checking whether the GitLab personal access token disappeared in GitLab browser.